# Proving a statement about stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm getting stuck on the following statement

> Suppose that $\tau$ is a stopping time on some filtered probability space $(\Omega,\cal{F},\cal{F}_t,\mu)$ and that $f:[0,+\infty]\to[0,+\infty]$ is a measurable function such that $f(t)\geq t$ for all $t\geq0$. Then, $f(\tau)$ is a stopping time as well.

It's straightforward to see that 
$$\{\omega:f(\tau(\omega))\leq t\}\subset \{\omega:\tau(\omega)\leq t\}\in \cal{F}_t$$

However, I'm unsure how to proceed form here. Could someone post a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume first that $f$ is nondecreasing. Then, for every $t$, there exists some $s\leqslant t$ such that $[f(\tau)\leqslant t]$ is either $[\tau\leqslant s]$ or $[\tau\lt s]$. And $[\tau\leqslant s]$ and $[\tau\lt s]$ are both in $\mathcal F_s$, which is a sub-sigma-algebra of $\mathcal F_t$.

In the general case, for every $t$, $[f(\tau)\leqslant t]=[\tau\in B_t]$ where $B_t=f^{-1}([0,t])$ hence $B_t\subseteq[0,t]$. Consider the class $\mathcal C_t$ of Borel subsets $B$ of $[0,t]$ such that $[\tau\in B]$ is in $\mathcal F_t$. The stopping property of $\tau$ implies that $[0,s]$ is in $\mathcal C_t$ for every $s\leqslant t$. Note that $\mathcal C_t$ is a sub-sigma-algebra of $\mathcal B_t$ the Borel sigma-algebra of $[0,t]$ and that the $\pi$-system $\{[0,s]\mid0\leqslant s\leqslant t\}$ generates  $\mathcal B_t$. Thus, Dynkin's $\lambda-\pi$ theorem asserts that $\mathcal C_t=\mathcal B_t$, which proves the property.